# Ruby rails iniciante

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Como crio um programa onde EU USO meu Nome e outputs com uma saudaçâo?

Comment: ruby é uma linguagem de programação, ruby on rails é um framework feito usando a linguagem ruby. Sua pergunta não deixa claro onde é que vc tem o problema.

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

```
puts 'Qual é seu nome?'
nome = gets.chomp
puts "E aí, #{nome}!"
```

### Sobre Ruby e Rails

Ruby é a linguagem. Ruby on Rails é o framework para construir aplicações web.

[A minha recomendação é que você estude primeiro a linguagem Ruby e depois se aprofunde no framework Rails.](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-learn-a-new-programming-language-faster-dc31ec8367cb) Isso vai fazer você sofrer menos na curva de aprendizagem.

### Brincando com I/O em Ruby

Tendo [instalado o Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/) em seu computador, basta criar um arquivo `ola.rb` (`.rb` é a extensão de arquivos Ruby) e começar a programar.

Para imprimir um texto na tela, você pode usar o método [`IO#puts`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/IO.html#method-i-puts). `puts` vem do inglês "*put string*".

```
puts 'Olá, meu nome é user104809!'
```

E é assim que se imprime um texto no console em Ruby. Para rodar esse código, basta executar `ruby ./ola.rb` no seu console.

Para receber o nome do usuário, pode usar o método [`IO#gets`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/IO.html#method-i-gets). Ele vai ser responsável por capturar um input do usuário. Como ele retorna uma String com uma linha em branco no final ([`/n`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) - sequência de escape), eu irei retirar utilizando o [`String#chomp`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-chomp).

```
puts 'Qual é seu nome?'
nome = gets.chomp
puts "E aí, #{nome}!"
```

O resultado fica algo como:

[image]

Veja que no último `IO#puts`, eu utilizei uma [interpolação de string](http://nomedojogo.com/2009/07/20/o-novo-sistema-de-interpolacao-do-ruby-1-9/) (`#{nome}`). Não se assuste! É bem simples. Ele só vai inserir na string o valor de uma expressão. Ou seja:

```
"um mais um é igual a {1 + 1}."
=> um mais um é igual a 2.
```

É a forma curta de fazer:

```
"um mais um é igual a " + (1 + 1).to_s + "."
```

Com a interpolação fica bem melhor de ler, né?! As interpolações estão disponíveis desde o [Ruby 1.9](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2007/12/25/ruby-1-9-0-released/).

### Onde aprender Ruby?

Existem algumas fontes muito boas para se aprender a linguagem. Se houver possibilidade, manda ver!

1. [No site oficial do **Ruby**](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/)
2. [Nos tutoriais interativos do **RubyMonk**](https://rubymonk.com)
3. [No *getting started* do Ruby em 15 minutos do **Try Ruby**](http://tryruby.org/levels/1/challenges/0)
4. [No livro **The Ruby Way**](http://therubyway.io)
5. [No grupo de estudos da comunidade do **Training Center**](https://github.com/training-center/ruby-study-group) (estou lá!)

Comment: Acredito que esse site pode ser de grande ajuda também: https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/17.10